# How to remove double " () " from final answer

Tags: python

The assignment

```
Write a Python program that accepts a sequence of comma-separated numbers from the user and generates a list and a tuple of those numbers

Sample data : 3, 5, 7, 23
Output :
List : \['3', ' 5', ' 7', ' 23'\]
Tuple : ('3', ' 5', ' 7', ' 23')
```

Code

```
emptyTuple = ()
a, b, c = input("Enter three values: ").split()  
elem = a,b,c

arr = list(emptyTuple)
arr.append(elem)
emptyTuple=tuple(arr)

 print(arr)
 print(emptyTuple)
```

Results

```
Enter three values: 88 55 22 
[('88', '55', '22')\]  -\>\>\>\> How do i take out  "()" from inside the list

(('88', '55', '22'),) -\>\>\>\> ALSO here i am getting double "()"
```

Answer (score 2):

`elem` is already a tuple. To make it a `list` you can do `list(elem)`

```
a, b, c = input("Enter three values: ").split()
elem = a, b, c
arr = list(elem)
print(arr) # ['88', '55', '22']
print(elem) # ['88', '55', '22']
```

Or better, use the returned value of `split` which is a `list` to not limit yourself with the number of inputs

```
numbers = input("Enter three values: ").split() # 88 55 22 34 88
tup = tuple(numbers)
print(numbers) # ['88', '55', '22', '34', '88']
print(tup) # ('88', '55', '22', '34', '88')
```

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify only 3 numbers but does specify comma separation. All you need is:

```
my_list = input("Enter numbers separated by a comma : ").split(',')  

my_tuple = tuple(my_list)

print(my_list, my_tuple)
```

Comment: I was just about to comment that nobody seemed to have picked up on the comma separation part, but you just have...

Comment: Look at the data the OP actually used `Enter three values: 88 55 22 `

Comment: But, as you say, the brief does not specify how many numbers, but everyone has picked up on 3 for some reason; including yourself in your code, even though you mention it not being specified in your opening paragraph :)

Comment: Oops. Corrected.

Comment: @Guy Yes, by nobody I meant the OP as well; both on the quantity of numbers and on being comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unpack the tuple in the print:

```
a, b, c = input("Enter three values: ").split()
elem = a, b, c
print(*elem, sep=', ')
```

if you want a list instead

```
arr = list(elem)
```

if the quotemarks are important

```
print(*(f'\'{n}\'' for n in elem), sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to check the number of tokens being input then why not allow for an arbitrary number? For example:

```
values = input('Enter some comma-separated values: ')

_list = [token.strip() for token in values.split(',')]
_tuple = tuple(_list)

print(_list)
print(_tuple)
```

**Console:**

```
Enter some comma-separated values: 1, 2, 3
['1', '2', '3']
('1', '2', '3')
```